# Key column doesn't exist in table, but I swear it does

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have been reading other stack overflow entries but can't figure out why I'm getting this error. Here's the details:

MySQL query number 1, seems to show there is a column named 'indyid' that is a primary key:

```
DESCRIBE INDICATORS;

indyid  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
INDICATORNAME   varchar(255)    YES         
INDICATORCODE   varchar(255)    YES
```

MySQL query number 2 attempts to add a foreign key column to an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE YEARS
ADD FOREIGN KEY (indyid)
REFERENCES INDICATORS (indyid);

Error Code 1072: Key Column 'indyid' doesn't exist in table
```

Assuming that maybe the error was referring to the fact that I don't have an 'indyid' column in my "YEARS" table, I tried to add it but got this error:

```
Error Code 1075: Incorrect table definition; 
there can only be one auto column and it must be defined as a key.
```

What gives? I appreciate you sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps the error is saying that `years(indyid)` doesn't exist.

Comment: So does this mean I should delete the "YEARS" primary key so I can add an auto_increment foreign key?

Comment: Can you provide the result of `DESCRIBE YEARS`, please?

Comment: Good news, got it all figured out thanks for your comments.

Comment: Then you should answer your own question and accept it (which is fine) or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the primary key from years and did a query that allowed me to add a column as a foreign key and auto_increment at the same time.